# DeclareMathOperator and fontawesome: Spacing problems

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, fontawesome

I am trying to use the symbol `\faPlus` from the latex package `fontawesome` and I have some troubles with the spacing.

I declare my symbol with
`\DeclareMathOperator\plus{\text{\rm\scriptsize\faPlus}}`
The `\text` is there because it is not a math command. The `\rm` is there because there is no "italics" version, and so to avoid problems, the size is just a choice otherwise it is too big.

My problem is that the spacing looks not well. For example, if I put `$\star\plus\star$` I get this:

[image]

But if I write `$(\star)\plus(\star)$` or `\langle\star\rangle\plus\langle\star\rangle` I get this:

[image]

where the symbol is clearly not centered.

Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}     % for \DeclareMathOperator macro
\usepackage{fontawesome} % for the \faPlus symbol

\DeclareMathOperator{\plus}{\textrm{\rm\scriptsize\faPlus}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \star\plus\star
\]
\[
  (\star)\plus(\star)
\]
\[
  \langle\star\rangle\plus\langle\star\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `\mathbin`, not the `\mathop` that's used by `\DeclareMathOperator`, which is for operators such as “sin” or “log”, not for binary operation symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}     % for math
\usepackage{fontawesome} % for the \faPlus symbol

\newcommand{\plus}{\mathbin{\textnormal{\scriptsize\faPlus}}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \star\plus\star
\]
\[
  (\star)\plus(\star)
\]
\[
  \langle\star\rangle\plus\langle\star\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `\rm` has been deprecated for 30 years.

I'd probably use `\scalebox`, though, so the symbol also properly scales in subscripts, and add a small space on either side, because the symbol `\faPlus` has a very tight bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}     % for \DeclareMathOperator macro
\usepackage{fontawesome} % for the \faPlus symbol
\usepackage{graphicx}    % for \scalebox

\newcommand{\plus}{\mathbin{\mspace{1mu}\text{\scalebox{0.7}{\faPlus}}\mspace{1mu}}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \star\plus\star_{a\plus b}
\]
\[
  (\star)\plus(\star)
\]
\[
  \langle\star\rangle\plus\langle\star\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I noticed that the problem had nothing to do with the symbol, and I edited the question to make it more general. Your answer is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroDC Please, roll back, possibly also adding the more general question. There are specific parts for the usage of `fontawesome` in this context, which are addressed to in the answer.

Comment: Rolled back. Thanks.